# Report model performance with GridSearchCV

Tags: classification, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I used  `GridSearchCV` to optimize random forest classifier on a dataset with X, y

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()

parameters = {'n_estimators': [40, 80, 160], 
              'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12, 24], 'max_depth': [2, 4, 8]}

clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, parameters, n_jobs=-1,
                   scoring='roc_auc',
                   cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle = True, n_splits=3))

clf.fit(X, y)

print("Best AUC:  {}".format(clf.best_score_))
```

and get

```
Best AUC:  0.8293403900021546
```

Not so bad, but not perfect.

Then I did a manual cross validation:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=None, shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    train_auc = roc_auc_score(y_train, clf.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1] )
    test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1] )
    
    print("Train AUC", train_auc, "Test AUC", test_auc)
```

and get

```
Train AUC 1.0 Test AUC 1.0
Train AUC 1.0 Test AUC 1.0
Train AUC 1.0 Test AUC 1.0
```

It turns out the best model is actually performing really well and classifying every sample correctly. But I assume it is the best model from the K-fold validations and not representative of the average model performance. `clf.best_score_` reports the average of the score from cross-validation. I wonder if that is the correct interpretation?

If so, what metric should I report for the model performance 1.0 or 0.83?

Answer (score 1):

Neither are correct estimates of performance.

Your 1.0 is obtained by scoring `clf.best_estimator_` on test folds, *which it has already seen*; it is the refit model (trained on all of `X`) from the grid search.  You refit `rfc` in the loop, but that seems to be with default parameters, and you don't use it to score anyway.  Even if you replaced `clf.best_estimator_` in this loop with a freshly retrained `rfc` with `clf.best_params_`, those best parameters were chosen based on the data in `X`, so this would be optimistically biased.

The 0.83 is more realistic, being based on out-of-fold scores, but it is still optimistically biased because you used that score to select hyperparameters.

To get an unbiased performance estimate, you need another test set.